# Change Task bar icon for Chromium Edge

Tags: taskbar, icons, chromium

I created a shortcut, then changed its icon: right-click-> Properties -> Change Icon -> selected a .ico file.

I dragged it to the taskbar and whenever I click on the taskbar icon, Edge opens in a new window with the old icon.

[image: My Task bar]

Note that I am using Chromium Edge not the default one.

How do I get it to open in the same window with the new icon?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change it and here's how:

1. Change the shortcut icon normally.
2. Pin it to the taskbar.
3. Right-click on the taskbar icon.
4. Right-click on Microsoft Edge Canary
5. Select properties > Change Icon > Select the .ico file.
6. Click on the taskbar icon, Edge will open in a new window.
7. Unpin the old icon and pin the new one.

Comment: I made Chromium Edge the Default Browser and that then works just like regular Edge (which is no longer default)